# Populate listView using handler or any other technique / update listView from outside onCreate

Tags: android, listview

I have member variable String mActivity[] which gets updated every 3 seconds through a function onConnected. onCreate connects the API, (using Api.connect()).
I have to show the data saved in mActivity, but I cannot update data from outside onConnect.

How to use handler or any other technique to update listView?

Full code is too long to post - so I'm posting snippets.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
mApiClient.connect();
}
```

String variable is declared as a member variable.

```
 @Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityRecognizedService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.requestActivityUpdates(mApiClient, 3000, pendingIntent);
}
```

onConnected calls ActivityRecognizedService which changes values of mActivity[] (by making an object of the Activity); hence values of mActivity changes every 3 seconds. I need to update this in listView.

Comment: where you are updating mActivity[] values?

Comment: In ActivityRecognizedService.class, that is being called by onConnected method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the new entries to your array, then call [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) on your adapter to update the `ListView`.

For example, you could do something like this:

```
private void refreshListView(List<String> newEntries) {
    // yourList is the List that has the data for your adapter
    yourList.clear();
    yourList.addAll(newEntries);
    // yourListAdapter is the adapter for your ListView
    yourListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

You can call this method from anywhere in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one

```
runOnUiThread (new Thread(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() {
            updateListview();
         }
     }));
```

Comment: When you are updating mActivity values, At that time in activity try to use above one